# How to make app which support all screens

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen

I have question, how i can make application which can support all densities and resolutions screens?

Comment: Please read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), it should answer this question pretty satisfactory.

Comment: Read the Android tutorial [`Supporting Multiple Screens`](http://jayxie.com/mirrors/android-sdk/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and also [`Designing UI for Multiple Screens`](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Different screen size, The following is a list of resource directories in an application that provides different layout designs for different screen sizes and different bitmap drawables for small, medium, high, and extra high density screens.

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

The following code in the Manifest supports all screens .

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
          android:normalScreens="true" 
          android:largeScreens="true"
          android:xlargeScreens="true"
          android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Comment: Sorry my bad... for stupid question, actually i try to say It possible  programmically find out the divice screen size and dp and then load the best resources and fit layout?

Comment: Thanks, now i know how to get the dimmensions, but how to set resources folder for each dimmension?

Comment: @user1582087 . Check this code.........................
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
  getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
  res = dm.heightPixels;
  
  if(res > 800)
  {
   setContentView(R.layout.main854);
  }
  else
  {
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }

Comment: Maybe i can load for example all folder with resource, but not just one file?